# How to integrate google signin authentication in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am barely 2 months with React and currently I am having issues with integrating google signin to my application. This is what I have tried so far but it's still not working and I don't know what I am not doing right. Please any help would be appreciated.

I have attached both files for your review in case you might want to see where the issue is coming from. Thank you very much.

firebase file

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

const config = {
    apiKey: "*** API KEY ***",
    authDomain: "*** PROJECT ID ***.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "*** PROJECT ID *** ",
    storageBucket: "*** PROJECT ID ***.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "*** SENDER ID ***",
    appId: "*** APP ID ***",
    measurementId: "*** MEASUREMENT ID ***"
  };

  firebase.initializeApp(config); // this creates and initializes a Firebase instance.

  export const auth = firebase.auth();
  export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

  //google auth utility

  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.setCustomParameters({prompt: 'select_account'}); //this always triggers the google pop-up for signin

  export const signInWithGoogle = () => auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

    export default firebase;
```

signin file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import FormInput from '../formInput/FormInput'
import '../signIn/SignIn.css';
import CustomButton from '../customButton/CustomButton';
import signInWithGoogle from '../../firebase/firebase';

class SignIn extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }
    }
    // onsubmit handler for the form 
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ email: '', password: '' });
    }
    //onchange handler for the input
    handleChange = (event) => {
        const { value, name, } = event.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sign-in">
                <h2>I already have an account</h2>
                <span>Sign in with your email and password</span>

                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <FormInput
                        type="email"
                        name="email"
                        value={this.state.email}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        label="email"
                        required
                    />

                    <FormInput
                        type="password"
                        name="password"
                        value={this.state.password}
                        handleChange={this.handleChange}
                        label="password"
                        required
                    />

                    <CustomButton type="submit">Sign In</CustomButton><br />
                    <CustomButton onclick={signInWithGoogle}>{''}Sign in with Google{''}</CustomButton>
                </form>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
export default SignIn;
```

Comment: @jns Firebase configuration data is not a credential. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482366

Comment: Thank you very much, although it's not a project for production. It's a portfolio project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to ask for an email and password from the user.

Add a `Google Signup` button to UI.

Change your `signInWithGoogle` function as below and on the above button click you can use this function in the `SignIn Component` to get the signing user info. Which you can save to a DB and update your state.

```
export const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  return auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then((res) => {
    console.log(res.user);
    return res.user;
  });
}
```

Also take a look at `auth().onAuthStateChanged` it is like an `rxjs Observable` with updated user info. Use this in your App file or ContextProvider to switch your UI from an un-authenticated page to authenticated page and vice-versa

Comment: Also you can check [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/user-authentication-firebase-react-apps/)  or [this](https://dev.to/gathoni/firebase-google-sign-in-with-react-3741) article for more info.

Comment: do i need to import any module from firebase because it's saying 'googleProvider' is not defined?

Comment: `const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()`

Comment: thank you...it worked for me. You have been very helpful and everyone that help out. I so much appreciate.